# Find the probability of $prob(x\ge 4| x\ge1)$ using the exponential distribution.

Tags: statistics

Find the probability of $prob(x\ge 4| x\ge1)$ using the exponential distribution.

$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge0$ is the exponetial distribution

S0  $prob(x\ge 4| x\ge1)=prob(x\ge 3)$ by the memory less property.
and then I would do

$P(x\ge3)=\int_{3}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x)}$

and I get

$=\lambda e^{-3\lambda}$ but would this be right

Comment: Everything is right until the last step where you computed the integral incorrectly.

Comment: yes I think It should be $e^{-3\lambda}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\mathbb{P}(X\ge 4| X\ge 1 )=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X\ge 4 \cap X \ge 1)}{\mathbb{P}(X\ge 1 )} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X\ge 4)}{\mathbb{P}(X\ge 1 )} = \frac{e^{-\lambda4}}{e^{-\lambda}}= e^{-\lambda 3}.
$$